# How to fork code from bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I going to update https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-robokassa to 1.8. How to edit source with saving ability to create pull request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Login to Bitbucket
- Go to that repository
- Click the 'Fork' button in the left sidebar to create a forked copy on your account
- `git clone` your fork locally
- Make and commit your changes
- Push changes to your fork
- Open a pull request